# clear shared preferences from myBackgroundMessageHandler

Tags: flutter

I want to clear shared preferences when I send a FCM message and app is in background. Inside `myBackgroundMessageHandler` method I am calling a method to clear them.

```
static Future<dynamic> myBackgroundMessageHandler(
      Map<String, dynamic> message) {
     clearPreferences();
}

static void clearPreferences() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.clear();
}
```

I am getting the following error:

> Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found
> for method getAll on channel plugins.flutter.io/shared_preferences)

Comment: What if the app isn't on background? Does that still happens?

Comment: @MiguelRuivo no, I have the shared preferences issue only when app is in background, since myBackgroundMessageHandler will not be called unless the app is in background

Comment: Which version of Flutter are you at?

Comment: Flutter 1.17.5 and Dart 2.8.4

Answer (score 1):

step 1)
go to Application.kt/Application.java (in my case is kotlin)

step 2)
add these line into Application class (in kotlin)

```
if (!registry!!.hasPlugin("io.flutter.plugins.sharedpreferences")) {
  SharedPreferencesPlugin.registerWith(registry!!.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.sharedpreferences.SharedPreferencesPlugin"));
}
```

remember import this as well

```
import io.flutter.plugins.sharedpreferences.SharedPreferencesPlugin
```

step 3)
run flutter clean -> flutter get -> uninstall your app

Answer (score 0):

The code is completely fine.

Just restart your emulator. If you didn't do a full restart by closing the emulator and open it up again, this error can propably occur, because it doesnt have the newly added plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Add `SharedPreferences.setMockInitialValues({})` to your code before the `runApp()` function inside the main function of Flutter App.
this fixed the error for me